# connecting Python 2.6.1 with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python 2.6.1 and I want to connect to MySQLdb, I installed mySQL in my system, and I am trying to connect **MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.6** from **http://www.codegood.com/archives/4** site but its not working 
while running my application its saying that **No module named MySQLdb**

please any one provide me the proper setup for MySQLdb.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the one from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/ ? (Yes, as in Py2.5 exe-file)

Comment: I have tried its not working is there any other which it works fine, and I am using windows xp

Answer (score 13):

The best setup for Windows that I've found:

http://www.codegood.com/downloads?dl_cat=2

EDIT: Removed original link (it's an ad farm now :( )

Comment: Excellent link, that saved me a huge hassle. Thank you!

Comment: Agree--thanks! (I was wary of installing from an unknown source, but that installer saved a ton of time.)

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Sketchy as it seemed, it saves so much time I just looked the other way.

Answer (score 4):

The module is not likely in your python search path..

Check to see if that module is in your *Python Path*... In windows...you may find it in the registry

HKLM\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.6\PythonPath

Be careful editing it...

You may also alter the Python Path programmaticly by the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('somepath_to_the_module_you_wanted')

import the_module_you_wanted
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm having trouble getting my installation to connect to MySQL because of this same problem. Although your answer here may be correct, but do you guys honestly expect newbies to start tinkling with registry just to get Python working with MySQL? Your answer may be right but I think it's risky

Comment: Helen, expressed in the above solution, there are two *TWO* means of solving your problem.  (One of them does not involve registry editing)  

The first is an editing of your machine's python module search path. In windows, the module search path is located in registry and  changes to it are *usually* done by the module installer.

The second suggested solution suites your cautious nature.  Python allows the python module search path to be modified (not permanently as in above) by code.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem and then I realised I was importing MySQLdb erroneously - it's case sensitive:

Incorrect: >>>import mysqldb

Correct: >>>import MySQLdb

Silly mistake, but cost me a few hours!

Answer (score 0):

generally, (good) python modules provide a 'setup.py' script that takes care of things like proper installation (google for 'distutils python').  MySQLdb is a "good" module in this sense.

since you're using windows, things might be a bit more complex.  I assume you already installed MySQLdb following the instructions and it still gives this problem.  what I would do is open a cmd.exe window, cd to the directory containing the 'setup.py' script and there type something like
C:\Python26\Python.exe setup.py install

if this does not work, then grab the module somewhere else, maybe at the place where it is actively developed: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Answer (score 0):

See this post on the mysql-python blog: [MySQL-python-1.2.3 beta 2 released](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2009/03/mysql-python-123-beta-2-released.html) - dated March 2009. Looks like MySQLdb for Python 2.6 is still a work in progress...

Comment: Hi Everitt,
               I have downloaded has u specified link, but in that its not there setup file, actually I am using windows XP

after installation we need to set any path ? if its not what could be the reason for " No module named MySQLdb" ?

Comment: see the answer with 2 votes above for setting the path. Which file did you install from the blog? Did you try easy_install MySQL-python? Have you tried importing from the Python shell? Also, take a look at these forum comments: http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3108914&forum_id=70460.

Answer (score 0):

I went for compiled binary , thats the best way to go on windows. There is a good source maintained by someone. 
I wrote about it here before because some months down the lane I will forget how I solved this and be searching Stack again :/
http://vangel.3ezy.com/archives/101-Python-2.4-2.5-2.6-and-2.7-Windows-MySQLdb-python-installation.html