# is it required to give path after installation MySQL db for Python 2.6

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python 2.6.1, MySQL4.0 in Windows platform and I have successfully installed MySQLdb.

Do we need to set any path for my python code and MySQLdb to successful run my application? Without any setting paths (in my code I am importing MySQLdb) I am getting **No module named MySQLdb** error is coming and I am not able to move further.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install MySQLdb? This sounds like your MySQLdb module is not within your PYTHONPATH which indicates some inconsistancy between how you installed Python itself and how you installed MySQLdb.

Or did you perhaps install a MySQLdb binary that was not targeted for your version of Python? Modules are normally put into version-dependant folders.

Comment: I have downloaded from http://www.codegood.com/archives/4  this site 
and installed, MySQLdb is there C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages in this path.
      how can know that MySQLdb binary that was not targeted for your version of Python?

Comment: Which of these packages did you install? I just tried it with http://www.codegood.com/download/4/ (1.2.3rc1-win32) and I could load the module.

Comment: Hi Gutmann,
           I tried which you specified above link but still its coming same Error.

I am using simple code with import MySQLdb, not using any complex code also

Comment: Does it also refuse to work when you're using IDLE? Could you perhaps post the content of your sys.path?

Comment: I am very new to Python. can u plz tell me where I can see the sys.path? 
But through command prompt wen to c:\Python26>python and >>> import MYSQLdb 
it running fine with out any errors
But through code its giving error, how I have set path and where?

Answer (score 0):

no, it is generally not required (not for good mannered modules like MySQLdb).

did you check my answer to your previous question 
[connecting Python 2.6.1 with MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135625/connecting-python-2-6-1-with-mysqldb)

Comment: Yes, I have seen and I did how u said (I used 'setup.py from C:\Python26\Tools\Scripts path and run C:\Python26\Python.exe setup.py install) but no use still its coming same error.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are installing any project-dependent library of python always install those libraries in respective virtual environment

```
1. pip install virtualenv
```

## This will install virtualenv, now create a virtual environment named miscellaneous

```
2. virtualenv miscellaneous
```

## This will create a virtual environment named miscellaneous in working directory

```
3. source miscellaneous/bin/activate
```

## This will initiate the virtual environment and now any library you will install will be installed in this environment

```
4. pip install MySQL-python
```